# Mongodb select field to return embedded document in array

Tags: mongodb

Given the example doc below:

```
{
  "_id" : "2",
  "objects" : [{
      "_id" : "1",
      "name" : "embedded "
    },{
      "_id" : "2",
      "name" : "embedded "
    },{
      "_id" : "3",
      "name" : "embedded "
    }],
  "name" : "gloss2"
}
```

Is it possible to return only one subdocument? That way I don't have to select the whole parent object, get the list, and loop through the list to get the object in question.

```
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "name" : "embedded"
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is it possible to return only one subdocument?

Yes, but not the way you want. If you do the following, you will only get back the first element of the array:

```
coll.find({_id:'2'}, { 'objects.0': 1})
```

However, what you really want is something that looks like the following:

```
coll.find({_id:'2', 'objects._id': '3'}, { 'objects.$' : 1})
```

Of course, that does not actually work in MongoDB.

Looking at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200399/), this is one of the reasons to use the "embedded object" instead of the "array of objects". With "embedded object" you could do the following:

```
coll.find({_id:'2'}, {'objects.3': 1}) // where 3 is the id of the third object
```

This lets you pick just the "embedded objects" you need.

> That way I don't have to select the whole parent object...

The thing with MongoDB is that the parent document is *always* fetched. Queries return top-level documents. This is baked into the whole architecture. Even if you request just a slice of the document the server still has to load the entire document into memory before serving you the requested piece.

The only way around this may be the new [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework), but that is not yet in the stable branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with mongo > 2.2 version.

db.collection.find({'objects._id':1},{'objects.$': true})

But you just get the first match element
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/

Answer (score 2):

You can return one subdocument, but you can't return one element from an array. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of mongodb (now is 2.6) there is a projection, `$elemMatch`, that help us in this case. 
If it helps someone, there are some examples in this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb 3.2 introduces $elemMatch with that you can get only one first matched document from the array of documents.

```
db.sample.find({_id:"2"},{objects:{$elemMatch:{_id:"2"}}})
```